# Some images are not showing in Flatlist when bad internet connection

Tags: react-native

I would like to ask, how **Image** component of React Native treat bad internet connection.

Is there number of attempts for fetching image, or is it limited by the time after which fetching stops?

I am asking because in Flatlist I see that with bad internet connection some images are never fetched, although all are of the same kind.

What I would like to achieve is to make app trying to fetch images for longer time or forever until it is loaded even with slow internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I know there is no try-attempt or time limit. It happens to me too sometimes the best way to do is using Loading Indicator.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/activityindicator
you can check out this link for that. Hope it is fine for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).